# what is a Stationary Time Series?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, seasonality

I have encountered this confusion:

I know any time series can be decomposed into three parts:
seasonal, trend and noise. where seasonal and trend are the non-stationary parts.
[image]

so I have this time series on internet(below) and it looks like the seasonal part of the previous time series:
[image]

why this is a stationary time series, isn't this also kind of seasonal time series?

Comment: Maybe you can share you tutorial if it's free/legal to see if what type of stationarity the author talks about.

Comment: @haventureinstatedmonicayet Dear Sir, of cos, there you go https://chih-ling-hsu.github.io/2017/03/20/time-series

Comment: @haventureinstatedmonicayet for weakly stationary series, I know the mean, variance and auto-co-variance must be constant. from the graph, I can easily check mean by baseline and variance by deviation from baseline. but for auto-co-variance between any Xt and Xt+p, how can I relate to the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not stationary because it has a seasonal component, i.e. it doesn't seem to pertain same statistical properties across its samples at different times. However, it can be *trend-stationary*, wide-sense *cyclostationary* (as in @TilefishPoele's answer).

Comment: Isn't $X_{t} = \sin (t + Y)$ where $ Y \sim U(0,2 \pi )$ a stationary process?

Comment: thanks for answering! But the below series is indeed a stationary time series according to the tutorial, I wondering isn’t it same as the seasonary part of the first time series

Comment: @TilefishPoele it is (at least it seems WSS), but e.g. $\sin t + Y$ is not. By seasonal component, I meant there is a clear seasonality in the series. If I had to do visual inspection only,  I wouldn't still call it as stationary. The tutorial probably means another type of stationarity, not in strict sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more strictly correct to label the seasonal process as a cyclostationary process.

The strict definition of a stationary stochastic process is that its unconditional joint pdf is unchanged when changing t. Clearly at non-periodical points the pdf changes. However at periodically interleaved points the distribution does not change, and overall the mean and the variance does not change over time.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. I understand the strict stationary means same distribution after time shift. Here I want to know more about weakly stationary as it is easier to explain. So my understanding for weakly stationary is that the mean and variance is constant over time, which is easy to check visually. but for the co-variance, its quite hard for me to check visually.

Comment: I believe every time series(no matter stationary or not) can be decomposed into three parts: seasonal, trend and noise. for the seasonal part, it is just a periodic wave like Xt=sin(at), where a is the period. I wondering if seasonal part + noise. isn't it similar to what you have written Xt=sin(t+Y)? I seem to be stucking in this puzzle. Your advise or correction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If time series is stationary if we have mean and variance constant over time windows (distribution of data across different time windows).

In the case of sine waves, we calculate. we will get mean and variance constant across different windows.

[image]

we can even justify this with ADF (Augmented Dickey-Fuller) test.

The Augmented Dickey-Fuller test is a type of statistical test called a unit root test.

The intuition behind a unit root test is that it determines how strongly a time series is defined by a trend.
There are a number of unit root tests and the Augmented Dickey-Fuller may be one of the more widely used. It uses an autoregressive model and optimizes an information criterion across multiple different lag values.

The null hypothesis of the test is that the time series can be represented by a unit root, that it is not stationary (has some time-dependent structure). The alternate hypothesis (rejecting the null hypothesis) is that the time series is stationary.

Null Hypothesis (H0): If failed to be rejected, it suggests the time series has a unit root, meaning it is non-stationary. It has some time-dependent structure.

Alternate Hypothesis (H1): The null hypothesis is rejected; it suggests the time series does not have a unit root, meaning it is stationary. It does not have a time-dependent structure.

[image]

We interpret this result using the p-value from the test. A p-value below a threshold (such as 5% or 1%) suggests we reject the null hypothesis (stationary), otherwise, a p-value above the threshold suggests we fail to reject the null hypothesis (non-stationary).

p-value > 0.05: Fail to reject the null hypothesis (H0), the data has a unit root and is non-stationary.

p-value <= 0.05: Reject the null hypothesis (H0), the data does not have a unit root and is stationary

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answering, but one doubt, perfect sine wave is not even a stochastic process, how can it be a stationary time series?

Comment: We can't mean over time w/o ergodicity assumption.

Comment: I think even with all the assumptions that mean and variance constant, the perfect sinusoidal wave is not a time series, because it is not even a stochastic process right? in order to be time series, all the data point must be random variables, please correct me if wrong. Thank you!